# Can I somehow figure out the type of an object in the base class constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, dynamic-cast

`Group` is a subclass of `Element`. Any group can contain elements (which can be groups, naturally). Each element registers itself with its containing group, which is passed into the constructor. But `dynamic_cast`does not seem to work until the constructor has finished.

Can I still automatically call `add_element` from the constructor but still ensure the object is ready enough for `dynamic_cast`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Group;

class Element {
public:
    Element(Group* group);
    virtual ~Element();

private:
    Group* group;
};

class Group : public Element {
public:
    Group(Group* group);
    void add_element(Element* element);
    void remove_element(Element* element);

private:
    std::vector<Element*> elements;
};

Element::Element(Group* group) : group(group)
{
    if (group)
        group->add_element(this);
}

Element::~Element()
{
    if (group)
        group->remove_element(this);
}

Group::Group(Group* group) : Element(group)
{
}

void Group::add_element(Element* element)
{
    if (dynamic_cast<Group*>(element))
        std::cout << "Adding a group" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Adding an element" << std::endl;
    elements.push_back(element);
}

void Group::remove_element(Element* element)
{
    // No need to implement this actually...
}

int main()
{
    Group* parent = new Group(0);
    Group* child = new Group(parent);
}
```

**Note:** The original question here was different, but it turned out that `dynamic_cast` wasn't the problem; `dynamic_cast` in the constructor is.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` *should* do the trick (if there is at least one `virtual` function in the base type), how are you trying to use it?

Comment: There are multiple virtual functions. The destructor, for example. (Added that to the sample code above to make that clear).

Comment: then dynamic_cast should work, perhaps you are casting to the wrong child

Comment: Are you compiling with RTTI off? That would render dynamic_cast useless (though I will admit I don't know what happens in that case--could/should be a compiler error).

Comment: The only difference I see in my code is that I'm actually working with references instead of pointers, but AFAIK that shouldn't be a problem. Also, I changed it all to pointers to see if that solves, didn't. (So I actually pass *element to add_element, which accepts a Element&.)

Comment: @SirPentor RTTI is on, dynamic_cast works fine in other places.

Comment: perhaps you should show us the implementation :)

Comment: Can you expand your simple example to show where dynamic_cast is not working?

Comment: Okay, let me build a compilable sample here...

Comment: Futzing around with the exact types of objects is almost always a design error. You should let polymorphism/inheritance take over. I.e., where Child1 and Child2 do things different, make _that_ into a (virtual) member function, and call it instead of finding out if Child1 or Child2 and acting accordingly. Best part is that when Children 3 to 17 come along, nothing has to be changed. Take a _hard_ look at [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com) on the matter (I believe in "Design and Evolution of C++", but I might be wrong)

Comment: @vonbrand Agreed, I'll use an overloaded add_element instead. But due to that issue I'm having, that's not working either :(

Comment: @futlib, make that problem into a new question, giving (skeleton) code that compiles, any special compilation instructions and exact environment, and explain what you expect (and why) and what you get. Note that you'll get answers from a spattering of operating systems/compilers...

Comment: Okay, figured it out: My problem is that I do that dynamic_cast IN add_element, i.e. during object construction. And that does not seem to work :(

Comment: @vonbrand I decided to update this question instead, hope you guys don't mind :( It's only a slight change, and I thought it's better then having a rather useless question lying around.